# Angular 2 cli: How to load the color picker? No system.config.js anymore?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I followed the usage guide on GitHub for loading everything, but I get this error "Error: Unexpected value `ColorPickerModule` imported by the module `AppModule`".

https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker

This is what I have so far

**app.module.ts**

```
import {ColorPickerModule} from 'angular2-color-picker';

imports: [ColorPickerModule]
```

**Toolbar component**

```
import {ColorPickerService} from 'angular2-color-picker';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-toolbar',
 templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss'],
 providers: [ColorPickerService]
})

export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private cpService:  ColorPickerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**toolbar template**

```
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"/>
```

I heard that the system.config.js is no longer used, but I'm not 100% sure. How can I load the color picker the proper way?

Comment: You should import the ColorPickerModule at the module that you declare your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the fact that the [angular2-color-picker](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker) module is not AoT compatible(yet)(and thus will not work when used in an ng CLI project). You can follow [this](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/issues/66) discussion for knowing when a PR with a solution will be merged into the repo's master branch.

Comment: I agree. I ended up using a different library to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples for webpack users in [`vendor.ts`](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/blob/master/examples_webpack/src/vendor.ts) you define

```
import 'angular2-color-picker/lib';
```

The same import is in [app.module.ts](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/blob/master/examples_webpack/src/app/app.module.ts).

> ```ts
> import {ColorPickerModule, ColorPickerService} from 'angular2-color-picker/lib';
>
> @NgModule({
>     imports: [
>         BrowserModule,
>         ColorPickerModule
>     ],
>     declarations: [
>         AppComponent
>     ],
>     providers: [ColorPickerService],
>     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

systemjs users might find this mapping

```ts
'angular2-color-picker': 'node_modules/angular2-color-picker',
```

which tells that the module should be installed by npm before loaded by the systemjs loader.

Comment: npm i --save angular2-color-picker

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything else,
it should working.